# How does sql lite work with files as database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to know how exactly does sqllite works when you are dealing with database on android. I know that it writes everything on file with .db extension. But how does it read or write one particular table? Does it fetch the whole file or just the related part and how exactly does it do these operations? Can someone please suggest me some link? I tried google but the links I found just explain how to write queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite operation on Android is not any different from SQLite operation on any other platform.

Very short answer to your question: SQLite file is split into pages of fixed size.
Each database object (table, index, etc) occupies some number of pages. If objects needs to grow (like new rows are inserted into table) it may allocate more new pages either from free page list, or by growing database file in size. If rows are deleted or object dropped, reclaimed free space goes into free page list. During any operation, SQLite engine tries to NOT fetch whole file, however it maintains page cache for higher performance.

You can find much more detailed explanations on [SQLite website](http://sqlite.org) in general, and about [SQLite database file format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) in particular.

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to read basics of the databases .
all the db frameworks are almost same in terms of working so 
you have to research on the basics of database (any).
here is some related information u can like

```
What does a database actually do to find out what matches a select statement?
```

To be blunt, it's a matter of brute force. Simply, it reads through each candidate record in the database and matches the expression to the fields. So, if you have "select * from table where name = 'fred'", it literally runs through each record, grabs the "name" field, and compares it to 'fred'.

Now, if the "table.name" field is indexed, then the database will (likely, but not necessarily) use the index first to locate the candidate records to apply the actual filter to.

This reduces the number of candidate records to apply the expression to, otherwise it will just do what we call a "table scan", i.e. read every row.

But fundamentally, however it locates the candidate records is separate from how it applies the actual filter expression, and, obviously, there are some clever optimizations that can be done.

```
How does a database interpret a join differently to a query with several "where key1 = key2" statements?
```

Well, a join is used to make a new "pseudo table", upon which the filter is applied. So, you have the filter criteria and the join criteria. The join criteria is used to build this "pseudo table" and then the filter is applied against that. Now, when interpreting the join, it's again the same issue as the filter -- brute force comparisons and index reads to build the subset for the "pseudo table".

```
How does the database store all its memory?
```

One of the keys to good database is how it manages its I/O buffers. But it basically matches RAM blocks to disk blocks. With the modern virtual memory managers, a simpler database can almost rely on the VM as its memory buffer manager. The high end DB'S do all this themselves.

```
How are indexes stored?
```

B+Trees typically, you should look it up. It's a straight forward technique that has been around for years. It's benefit is shared with most any balanced tree: consistent access to the nodes, plus all the leaf nodes are linked so you can easily traverse from node to node in key order. So, with an index, the rows can be considered "sorted" for specific fields in the database, and the database can leverage that information to it benefit for optimizations. This is distinct from, say, using a hash table for an index, which only lets you get to a specific record quickly. In a B-Tree you can quickly get not just to a specific record, but to a point within a sorted list.

The actual mechanics of storing and indexing rows in the database are really pretty straight forward and well understood. The game is managing buffers, and converting SQL in to efficient query paths to leverage these basic storage idioms.

Then, there's the whole multi-users, locking, logging, and transactions complexity on top of the storage idiom.